# Efficient implementations of Searching & Sorting Algorithms in Java

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, search, sorting

Does anyone have a good reference for a set of Java code implementations of common searching and sorting algorithms.

There are many ways to skin a cat (its easy to find Java code of various algos on the net), however is there a list of the most efficient ways in Java to implement these various algorithms?

There is for example the http://www.algorithmist.com but most implementations are in C/C++.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the Java Standard Library source code itself.

The [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) classes have binary search and binary sort implementations which you can study.

Here's the source for Collections.java from openjdk: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the book "Algorithms in Java (parts 1-4)" by Sedgewick useful. The code is [available online](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/Algs3.java1-4/code.txt), but it might be hard to understand without the book.

Answer (score 1):

Some standard Algorithms for Maps, Sets, Lists etc. are available. You have to  [download the src.zip from the Oracle-Java homepage](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), where it is available.

For common use cases, the algorithms should be pretty efficient, but of course, for every algorithm there is a worst-case scenario for the data, to be provided. So in exceptional cases, you will be able to find or produce better ones.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime complexity of an algorithm is indifferent to the programming language it's implemented in - so you shouldn't *really* care too much.  But since you ask, I would consider using [grepcode](http://www.grepcode.com).  For example, look what I [found](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=java%20quicksort) when i searched "java quicksort".

Comment: Yes I understand, the core is the same but some impls have greater overheads, use additional vars where one isnt required (say keeping counters etc).

Comment: Two points:  1, if you understand, then why do you care?  The impl gains will be drowned out as soon as you start using large enough data sets.  2.  I listed grepcode explicitly because you asked.

Answer (score 0):

https://intelligentjava.wordpress.com/2014/07/05/sorting-algorithms/ has good review with implementations and benchmark for performance comparison.