# How to increase Autocomplete search speed?

Tags: android, performance

Its a dictionary search and as a person enters text, suggestions pop out.
The database is an English dictionary.

```
//Search System
        final Context ctx = this;
        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                if (autoCompleteTextView.getText().length() >= 2) {
                    DbHandler handler = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    final ArrayList<String> Deflist = handler.getSearchList(autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().trim());
                    suggestions = Deflist;


                    handler.close();
                    if (Deflist != null) {

                        Search.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Deflist);
                                autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



            }
        });
```

**Database Code**

```
 public void indexDB()
    {
        try{

            getWritableDatabase().execSQL("CREATE INDEX words_index ON entries(word)");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public ArrayList<String> getSearchList(String partWord) {

        try {
            if (partWord == "") {
                return null;
            }


            ArrayList<Definition> DefList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
            Definition definition = null;
            Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE word LIKE '" + partWord + "%'", null);

            try {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));

                        if (!test.contains(word)) {
                            test.add(word);

                        }


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                cursor.close();
            }

            return test;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
```

}

I have tried to index it, set limit to 2 or more to begin search and even tried to run in a separate thread(Dropped the idea inconsistency of multi threading). Is there a way to make it really fast?

Comment: instead of serching from the hole table why dont you short the table on the basis of alphabets

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava its a Dictionary DB, its already sorted.

Comment: You mean, you have followed this? https://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html

Comment: bro then why dont you check the word  like a question of permutation like checking the position of word "Hello" fr ex- we first check no of word for H then e and so on this will reduce the effort

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava see, it works like a google search, I enter He, it shows words starting from He, then Hel is entered and it shows words from Hel... and so on. What you are suggesting is for finding a specific word.

Comment: @cricket_007 How much difference will Match make against like? If you know, please explain it to me. I just want to make this search quicker.

Comment: Full Text Search is quick, from my experience. A full database scan for a LIKE pattern isn't optimized for quick search results

Comment: Depending on your data, you can try using ElasticSearch. https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch. This is not am answer just an alternative.

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay I will try that. I was hoping for a magical Elastic Search-eque way to make it quicker.

Comment: As far as I know, Apache Lucene can't be ran on Android.

Comment: @GauravSharma hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159834/efficient-implementations-of-searching-sorting-algorithms-in-java try to take some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimize search on the database we can create a virtual full text search table and passing on the data of the table to searched on to the FTS table.

I have implemented an API for it. This API also uses prediction to get to the closest word related to the search query.

link - https://github.com/gauravat16/Smart-Search

```
    PredictiveSearch search = new PredictiveSearch(getApplicationContext());
      ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
      columns.add("word");
  try {
          search.createFTS4Table("learn.db", "entries", columns);
          search.ftsRebuilder(); //Use it to rebulid after any change
          ArrayList<String> resp1 = search.getSearchList("2"); //Get result w/o stemming
          ArrayList<String> resp2 = search.getGuessWord("2"); //Get result with stemming - predictive

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          search.close();
      }
```